# How to get all variable with "Required" As her value? On a get cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to build a page that use API from another site. I'm kind noob on this so my question can be silly.
This site have a bunch of category and on each of this category there are different fields that have to be filled so you can post an item.
So instead of me creating a page for each category, and try to pass a get that is already available on their API get the variable that have `Required` as it value so I can pass it to my code to fill it the right way.

So if I pass:

```
curl -X GET -H 'Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN' https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/MLA1055
```

It returns me a lot of results, and on some of it are:

```
"shipping_profile": "optional",
"show_contact_information": false,
"simple_shipping": "optional",
"stock": "required"
```

So my idea is if there is a way to get the the name of the result that will be `stock`. So I can put it on my code so the user can fill it and I don't have to do category by category...
Like I said before. I'm noob at `PHP` and `cURL`, but I have some experience with coding, is just a new language, hope you guys can help me.

Comment: from your snippet, it looks like a JSON data, can you post the WHOLE result so that we can determine how to get your exact JSON path?

Comment: You can see it here https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/MLA1055

Answer (score 0):

First, you would have to convert the JSON string from API into an object understood by PHP, we have [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for this:

```
//let's assume JSON data has been downloaded and stored in data.json file
$jsonString = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/data.json');
$jsonObject = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

Next, from the URL you gave in the comment, I can see that the `"required"` data is stored inside `settings` key. You can use JSON viewer tools to visualize the data.

[image]

> I'm using online [JSON viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) tools

Extract it to another variable, or just loop through the elements:

```
$arrayRequired = array();

foreach($jsonObject['settings'] as $key => $setting){
    if($setting === 'required'){
        $arrayRequired[] = $key;
    }
}
```

Your required keys now stored inside `$arrayRequired` variable:

```
print_r($arrayRequired);

Array
(
    [0] => immediate_payment
    [1] => price
    [2] => stock
)
```

That's it.

Comment: Tks, im at work rn... When I get home I'll test it. But seems exactly what I was looking for.